# Microsoft Azure web hosting for email with custom domain

Tags: azure, web, hosting

I registered a domain, let’s say `example.com`, and want Microsoft Azure to do the web hosting so I can send and receive emails as `me@example.com`. How do I do that?

I basically want to get rid of my current web hosting company (`myhosting.example`) and want to use Azure instead because it is more convenient.

As a client I want to use Microsoft Outlook on my PC at home.

Is that even possible?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions similar to this there.

Answer (score 4):

As part of azure you can access office 365. It uses the same custom domains. You will require a license for office 365. These start at around $4.
Using office 365 you can both send and relay e-mails.
Access of 365 is via https://portal.office.com

Answer (score 1):

You can host your custom domains in Azure using [Azure DNS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/dns/) also you can build your own mail servers ..etc. (Build VMs then install ur mail server)

However I would recommend using Office 365, if its about hosting a mail server.